# Trouble Selecting Multipart (Multi Warehouse) Orders

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am trying to get the order to be split into parts. 1, 3, 20. Doesn't matter. 
And each part means that it is taking those product from a different warehouse.

I have tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE w_orders (
   order_id int,
   customer_id int,

   PRIMARY KEY( order_id )
);
CREATE TABLE w_order_items (
   order_item_id int,
   order_id int,
   warehouse_id int,
   product_id int,
   quantity int,
   base_price int,

   PRIMARY KEY( order_item_id )
);
CREATE TABLE w_order_parts (
   order_part_id int,
   order_id int,
   part int,
   warehouse_id int,
   shipped int,

   PRIMARY KEY( order_part_id )
);
```

`w_orders` is where the unique order ID is assigned, and where the client is assigned.

`w_order_items` are all the products in the order, from multiple warehouses.

And `w_order_parts` is what I have trouble with. I need this table, because in here, I indicate wether the order from this particular warehouse was shipped.

---

**This is the structure I am trying to achieve:** [image: Image Preview]

*I understand that this needs to be processed with PHP to look like this. I am not here asking about that. Just stuck with the design of the database and the selecting of it.*

When I try to query I get multiple of the same `w_order_items`.

```
SELECT

    w_orders.order_id,
    w_orders.customer_id,

    w_order_items.order_item_id,
    w_order_items.order_id,
    w_order_items.warehouse_id,
    w_order_items.product_id,
    w_order_items.quantity,
    w_order_items.base_price,

    w_order_parts.order_part_id,
    w_order_parts.order_id,
    w_order_parts.part,
    w_order_parts.warehouse_id,
    w_order_parts.shipped

FROM
    w_orders

LEFT JOIN w_order_items
    ON w_orders.order_id = w_order_items.order_id

LEFT JOIN w_order_parts
    ON w_orders.order_id = w_order_parts.order_id


WHERE w_orders.order_id = '100'
```

**Heres a link to [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27bf7/1)**

---

Is this a good table design for what I am trying to achieve and how do I `SELECT` the items properly like in the image above?

Comment: The exact output you want to achieve is usually best handled in the presentation layer (e.g. PHP).  How are you using MySQL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah I know that. Haven't gotten there because I've been stuck with the design and the selecting of the MySQL. The image above is just to provide visual aid as to how it will function when finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to rearrange the joins and include a join on the warehouse id...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27bf7/3

```
SELECT

    w_orders.order_id,
    w_orders.customer_id,

    w_order_items.order_item_id,
    w_order_items.order_id,
    w_order_items.warehouse_id,
    w_order_items.product_id,
    w_order_items.quantity,
    w_order_items.base_price

FROM
    w_orders

LEFT JOIN w_order_parts
    ON w_order_parts.order_id = w_orders.order_id

LEFT JOIN w_order_items
    ON  w_order_items.order_id     = w_order_parts.order_id
    AND w_order_items.warehouse_id = w_order_parts.warehouse_id


WHERE
    w_orders.order_id = '9898'

ORDER BY
    w_orders.customer_id,
    w_orders.order_id,
    w_order_parts.warehouse_id,
    w_order_items.order_item_id
```

This assumes that every order item matches a warehouse in the order parts table.

The order by also prepares your results for later formatting.

Comment: Yeah this works as I wanted. Thanks! Do you think this is an efficient database design? It is important that I can update `w_order_parts.order_part_id` to shipped or other statuses as needed.

Comment: Ideally I think that the order items should have an `order_part_id` to make relationships more clear.  *(An order is make up from parts, which is made up from items)*.  But other than that, it's fine.

Comment: Wont that make it more difficult to select? I'd have to select parts with the order_id, then select the products linked to that part.

Comment: It depends on your exact business case.  A first principle of relational database design is normalisation.  Don't repeat data in multiple tables.  You have the order_id in both items and parts, you have warehouse_id in both too.  That's a breach of normalisation *(You only **need** them in the part table if the item table has a part_id)*.  Your initial design should be as normalised as possible, as that's flexible and maintainable.  Then, if you actually encounter real world performance issues, denormalise slightly if necessary.  This sounds like premature optimisation to me.

Comment: I definitely took that into consideration linking them to `w_order_parts` instead. And I agree it would make it way more coherent. But I want the endusers to be able to easily shift products between warehouses. Thats why I didn't want to tie them to `w_order_parts`. But I needed it for the shipping status. Wasn't not sure how I would handle that if they were linked to `w_order_parts` instead of the `w_orders `.

Comment: Then you're conflating a "part" with a "warehouse".  Do "parts" actually represent anything other than a retrospective abstraction?   It sounds like you just need an Items table.  If each item is *actually* assigned a warehouse before shipping, then give it a warehouse id field.  Then have a fulfillment table `(warehouse_id, order_id, shipped timestamp, etc)`.  If it's possible to have only some items fulfilled at the same time have a link table between fulfillments and actual order items.  The possibilities are endless, and without in-depth detail on your business processed, I can't say...

Comment: As a rule of thumb try to represent either something ***real and tangible*** from a business process, or represent a ***relationship*** between such entities.  If you have order, parts, items, warehouses, then they each get their own table, and the links tables between them.  *(If an entity always relates to one parent, you just need a field, not a whole new link table.)*  Right now, with only a vague understanding of the process you're modelling, I'm not convinced that a `part` it a real entity.  And if it is, only a part or an item should reference a warehouse *(for example)*.

Comment: Perhaps open a new question.  Describe your business processes in complete detail, then ask people how they would implement that in a relational database.

Comment: I don't actually need the "parts" no. They represent a warehouse. I like the fulfillment table idea, and I will create a sample like that now actually. Orders are fulfilled—shipped as they come to the warehouse. When the order is inserted into this database, it has actually been reserved for the user and taken out of stock. So we know that all the items are available and can ship them all at once. Thats why we don't need to ship them individually. Thank you :)